Tmux copy mode fails under WSL
When I enter copy mode, I press space to start copying but instead nothing is copied and the cursor jumps to the bottom of the screen as if I had pressed the page down key. No text is highlighted or copied. When I enable vi copy mode, it also fails to highlight text using the v command to start copying. In this case nothing on the screen changes after pressing v.
This is using the default tmux configuration on WSL (version 2 with Ubuntu) using the builtin terminal (also happens when I use terminator in wsl). I have tried various tmux configurations, I have tried changing the keyboard language. I always get the same result.
